# Check if any nested list within a 2d list both contains one value and does not contain another

Tags: python, list

I'm making a card game in python where the cards are stored in a 2D list, where the first layer of the list is each card and the second layer is the values a card has. I'm trying to make an `if` statement that checks if any card a player has in their hand (that is, any nested list within the list that is the player's hand) contains a specific string in position 0 and does not contain an integer in position 5. The code is this:

`if ("Melee" in [x[0] for x in p1_hand] and 0 not in [x[5] for x in p1_hand])`

(followed by a bunch of `or`s for additional checks, which I know work properly and aren't relevant)

I read on another Stack Overflow question that this is the most efficient way to check if an item exists within a 2D list, so I did it like this. However, it does not work for my purposes.

What I'm trying to do is check if there is any item in p1_hand where position 0 (`p1_hand[x][0]`) is "Melee" and position 5 (`p1_hand[x][5]`) is not 0 (what I'm actually checking for is if it's 1 or higher, but using operators here returns an error). The results of the code I have at the moment are seemingly random, I can't track down any pattern whatsoever as to when this `if` statement returns true or false.

I am totally at a loss as to how to get this to work, especially how to make a working solution which can fit into a single line in an `if` statement (which is important for what I'm trying to do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're checking if there's any card named `Melee` and any card where the value isn't 0. But they're not necessarily the same card.

Use the `any()` function to test both conditions on each card in the list.

```
if any(x[0] == "Melee" and x[5] != 0 for x in p1_hand):
```